# Productivity Power Tools not working in VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, productivity-power-tools

I just installed Productivity Power Tools for VS 2017 and the installer said everything was successful, I do see the location for it in Tools > Options.  However when I click on it it doesn't have the option to enable/disable certain features (Custom Document Well for example).

I've tried uninstalling and re-installing with no success.  The old behavior used to show the ability to enable/disable features on when you click on it.  Now it just shows the output of the HTML copy tab

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are separate installers for the individual features now. [The main package should be installing the parts in the background](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.ProductivityPowerPack2017), but you can force the installation manually if needed by downloading the individual parts. The link to each individual part can be found on the page of the main installer.

The enable disable option has been removed in favor of the ability to uninstall/disable individual extensions from the tools & extensions window:

> **Note:** The Productivity Power Tools does not install a page in Tools->Options for enabling and disabling individual Productivity Power Tools. For Visual Studio 2017, we have release all components as separate extensions. So, you can now enable and disable them through Extensions and Updates. Hence, there is no longer a need for the page in Tools->Options.

I've personally had to use the "Reset Productivity Power Tools" option from the Tools menu after the latest upgrade.

Comment: i tried downloading the Custom Document Well from https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.CustomDocumentWell and it says its already installed.  Yet I still don't see it anywhere in my options (did a search for custom)

Comment: That "Rest Productivity Power Tools" option did it for me. I was wondering why I couldn't see any options for the extension and nothing worked. Resetting did it and every feature was installed correctly.

Comment: `Use the "Reset Productivity Power Tools" option from the Tools menu` worked for me. Odd that I had to do that after a fresh installation (read: not an update), but it works fine now.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of this from a UX perspective. People install the Productivity Power Tools extension, and expect to be able to control its behaviour from the options menu (like any built-in VS behaviour or many other tools). It's counter-intuitive to look up particular config from the extensions menu when you didn't install that specifically, and you can't find it by typing "Productivity Power Tools" in the search box. A piece-by-piece uninstaller would make sense to me only if those items were actually installed individually.

Comment: After a recent upgrade mine stopped working and there was no sign of the "Reset Productivity Power Tools" option. However I found that when I looked in Tools, Extensions & Updates all the individual tools were there and marked as disabled. I enabled them there and they started working again.

Comment: I was not finding this "Reset Productiviy Power Tools" so I uninstall PPT, installed again and worked ok! I did uninstallation and installation by Tools -> Extensions & Updates

Answer (score 6):

I have faced this type of problem. Just click on Reset Productivity Power Tools under Tools menu. If you have already install Productivity Power Tools.

here is a link

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/18576/productivity-power-pack-not-showing-in-tools-optio.html

Answer (score 0):

Posting this so it may help someone.

In my case, i tried to install productivity power tools by downloading it from [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.ProductivityPowerPack2017) and then executed downloaded `.vsix` file which didn't work and got an error message like "*This extension is already installed to all applicable products*". Thought probably had installed it before and went to search it's trace under `Tools=> Options` but unfortunately couldn't find anything related to this extension. Also, couldn't find options like "*Reset Productivity Power Tools*" under Tools menu.

Later doing this worked for me, `Tools => Extensions and Updates` in the left pane selected `Online => Visual Studio Marketplace => Tools` option and searched for *Productivity Power Tools* downloaded and installed from there.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the installation of Productivity Power Tools failed for **Visual Studio Comunity 2017**, I updated the VS 2017, tried to install again the Productivity Power Tools and all worked like a charm.

Answer (score -2):

Please go the following direction below:

"ReSharper/Extension >>Options >>Environment >>Keyboard & Menus >>Hide overridden VS menu items",
Could you try untick that checkbox feature once again start for "Remove and Sort Using on **Save**".